# programtical Setting the backgroundImage of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dom

I'm trying to set the backgroundImage of an HTML element via:

`element.style.backgroundImage = "url(localPath/to/image.gif, basePath);"`

Unfortunately, the image is not being displayed and I think it has to do with the base-path, because I have done this before without the base-path.

Oddly, if I remove the basePath, I get an error saying that no such URL exists, but I do not get an error if I keep the basePath.

1. How can I properly set the backgroundImage?
2. Is there another method of setting the backgroundImage?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't pass a basePath to the url value of the backgroundImage, just a URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use `basePath` and you need to remove the semi-colon as part of the CSS value:

```
element.style.backgroundImage = "url(localPath/to/image.gif)";
```

Comment: Can I specify the full URL? or will it automatically append whatever argument I pass to the URL of the page?

Comment: You can specify either an absolute URL (http://www.example.com/...) or a relative URL (../images/file.ext). Nothing will be appended in either case. You can dynamically build the URL with a variable though, like this: `= "url(" + variable + ")";` Whatever you wind up doing, it will be the path to the image and the current page URL will not be included.